# Edit money values in WPF form

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a strange problem in a WPF application. The user is supposed to enter invoices with at least one line into a DataGrid. One field contains the amount, thus it looks like `i,ff`, i.e. the integral part with at least one digit, a comma (I am in Europe) and two fractional digits.

When the user focuses into the field the integral part can be overwritten, the comma remains fixed and the fractional part can be also overwritten. So the user types in the integral part, then has to use cursor right to skip over the comma and then type the fractional part of the amount.

This behavior has been criticized by my users as they are accountants and used to type the entire amount at once. So my question is: is there a way to make the entire field overwritable?

Here is the XAML for that DataGrid column:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colBetBtto"
    Header="Brutto"
    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderRightAligned}"
    Width="*"
    CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellRightAligned}"
    Binding="{Binding Path=BttoBetrag, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

The cell style is:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellRightAligned" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,1,0" />
</Style>
```

Any ideas what causes that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the `DataGridTextColumn` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and apply the `StringFormat` only to the read-only `TextBlock`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Brutto" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellRightAligned}" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BttoBetrag, StringFormat=N2}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding BttoBetrag}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Then the value in the editable `TextBox` should be presented without any specific format.

**Edit:**

> Your suggested solution works so that during editing the comma is gone but the user has to click twice on the cell in order to edit the value. What I need is that with tab sequence or by single click the entire cell value is selected and can be changed.

This is a new question/issue, isn't it?

Anyway, you could handle the `GotFocus` event for the `DataGrid`:

```
private void dataGrid_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(DataGridCell))
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
        dataGrid.BeginEdit(e);
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

> What I am expecting is the user to tab or click into the column field. Then it's entire contents should get highlighted and the user can enter an amount consisting of digits, a comma and again digits overwriting the previous contents.

Try to handle the event like this then:

```
private void dataGrid_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = e.OriginalSource as DataGridCell;
    if (cell != null)
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
        dataGrid.BeginEdit(e);

        cell.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            ContentPresenter cp = cell.Content as ContentPresenter;
            if (cp != null && VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(cp) > 0)
            {
                TextBox textBox = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(cp, 0) as TextBox;
                if (textBox != null)
                {
                    Keyboard.Focus(textBox);
                    textBox.SelectAll();
                }
            }
        }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
}
```

You may also want to apply the `StringFormat` to the `TextBox`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding BttoBetrag, StringFormat=N2}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Comment: mm8 thank you once again for your help. Your suggested solution works so that during editing the comma is gone but the user has to click twice on the cell in order to edit the value. What I need is that with tab sequence or by single click the entire cell value is selected and can be changed.

Comment: Please see my edit. But please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: Sorry mm8, this is still the same issue. What I am expecting is the user to tab or click into the column field. Then it's **entire** contents should get highlighted and the user can enter an amount consisting of digits, a comma and again digits overwriting the previous contents. With my original version only the integral part of the amount up to the decimal point (ie. comma) was selected. With your suggestion there is no comma (as the textbox has no format in the CellEditingTemplate) but the contents of the cell is unselected and in order to edit it the user has to double-click on it or delete

Comment: That used to be the standard editing behavior in WinForms, therefore people are used to it and are resistant to accept something different...

Comment: Thank you mm8. It is frustrating that for simple standard editing behavior one needs tons of extra code in WPF. I doubt that this technology is suitable for commercial applications. The users don't need the blinky features of WPF but solid standard software functionality. I'll go back to WinForms again.